# Does ASP.NET MVC work under IIS 5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have to use XP as my development machine so far. But VS 2008's development server does not seem to work, very strange! (VS 2005's working well). Could I use IIS 5.1 to run ASP.NET MVC?

Thanks!

Comment: If I recall correctly Cassini doesn't work with MVC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can. Check out this post for details about how: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/dorony/archive/2007/12/15/using-asp-net-mvc-on-iis-5.aspx

Comment: I saw that. But somehow, the "OK" button is disabled when I tried to add a new mapping. Any idea? Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure. I've never tried it and I don't have an XP box to try it on now. Could it be a permissions problem? Are you running as administrator?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use IIS on XP to run MVC.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I got mine to work. Change the url extensions to .aspx in the routing.

Answer (score 0):

Url rewriting can help you to solve the problem. I've implemented solution allowing to deploy MVC application at any IIS version even when virtual hosting is used.
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/iis-aspnet-url-rewriting.aspx